# Dereferencing on an Array of Hashes in Perl?

Tags: perl, dereference

The data is stored in @emailaddresses as follows:

```
$VAR1 = { 'email' => 'abc@google.com' };
$VAR2 = { 'email' => 'cde@google.com' };
$VAR3 = { 'email' => 'efg@google.com' };
$VAR4 = { 'email' => 'hij@google.com' };
```

When I print @emailaddresses (print @emailaddresses), it prints `HASH(0x...)` instead of the values in the array. How can I print the values?

Comment: What it's printing is the memory address of the hash stored in a particular element of the array: `HASH(0x...)`

Hunter's answer below performs the dereferencing of that hash reference with the `->` operator.

Comment: what do you *want* to print?  which "values"?

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop through your array and print out each addresses 'email' value:

```
my @emailaddresses = ...;

for my $addr ( @emailaddresses ) {
   print $addr->{email}, "\n";
}
```

better yet, wrap this logic in a function:

```
sub print_email_addresses {
   my @addresses = @_;

   for my $addr ( @addresses ) {
      print $addr->{email}, "\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: whether to wrap it in a function or not makes sense depends a lot on what else is happening, so I wouldn't say "better yet"

Comment: @ysth I imagine you might want to print a data structure more than once.